# EKS - Kubernetes - ES - Error: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, file-descriptor, amazon-eks

After downgrading `Docker` from `18.09` to `18.06` in EKS nodes using `yum`, the `ES` pod on the node goes into crash-loop with the following error in the logs:

```
max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
```

I do not think that this is because of `Docker` version, but because of default settings of the package. Adding `fs.file-max=65536` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` did not help. Also, there is nothing especial in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the settings in this file: `/etc/sysconfig/docker`

It is as follows:

```
OPTIONS="--default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096"
```

By commenting out that line, the issue was resolved.

Comment: This is not an answer to your initial question. Please remove this answer and edit the question instead.